# Can't open google docs duplicated document in script

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm writing a script which duplicates a template spreadsheet, and will eventually populate it. Unfortunately the last "return" line of my function is giving me an error "Document is missing (perhaps it was deleted?)"

A lot of information out there on that error suggests permission problems but even though there is an error in "openById()" The document is actually created and I can edit it, in the web browser.

```
function createDuplicateDocument(sourceId, name) {
    var source = DriveApp.getFileById(sourceId);
    var newFile = source.makeCopy(name, DriveApp.getFolderById(FOLDER));
    return DocumentApp.openById(newFile.getId());
}
```

I've looked at code at https://gist.github.com/mhawksey/1170597 and it seems to use the lines:

```
var docid = DocsList.getFileById(templateid).makeCopy().getId();
var doc = DocumentApp.openById(docid);
```

The "DocsList" seems to have been deprecated in favour of the DriveApp but converting the lines to use this Interface still yeilds the same result.

Answer (score 0):

Asked this question on the Google Docs forums and got an answer there.

Basically as I was making a copy of a spreadsheet I had to open the created document with SpreadsheetApp as opposed to DocumentApp. Simple as that but I could not find the solution to the problem and kicking myself that it was so easy.